# Export Excel data to CSV file using the Excel file name

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am using a solution provided by the user The_Barman for exporting specific cells from an Excel document to a CSV document:

```
Sub WriteCSVFile()

Dim My_filenumber As Integer
Dim logSTR As String

My_filenumber = FreeFile

logSTR = logSTR & Cells(18, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(19, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(20, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(21, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(27, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(28, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(29, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(30, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(31, "C").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(32, "C").Value & " , "

Open "C:\temp\Filename.csv" For Append As #My_filenumber
    Print #My_filenumber, logSTR
Close #My_filenumber

End Sub
```

I am wondering if it would be possible and how I would go about having the CSV file name reference the originating Excel document's filename that the VBA script was run on, rather than having to manually input it into the code each time.

i.e. have "C:\temp\Filename.csv" save as "C:\temp\ExcelSpreadsheet.csv" without manually inputting the "ExcelSpreadsheet" filename each time it is run:

`Open "C:\temp\Filename.csv" For Append As #My_filenumber
        Print #My_filenumber, logSTR
    Close #My_filenumber`

Thank you for any assistance you may provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub WriteCSVFile()

    Dim My_filenumber As Integer
    Dim logSTR As String

    My_filenumber = FreeFile

    logSTR = logSTR & Cells(18, "C").Value & " , "
    logSTR = logSTR & Cells(19, "C").Value & " , "
    logSTR = logSTR & Cells(20, "C").Value & " , "
    logSTR = logSTR & Cells(21, "C").Value & " , "
    logSTR = logSTR & Cells(27, "C").Value & " , "
    logSTR = logSTR & Cells(28, "C").Value & " , "
    logSTR = logSTR & Cells(29, "C").Value & " , "
    logSTR = logSTR & Cells(30, "C").Value & " , "
    logSTR = logSTR & Cells(31, "C").Value & " , "
    logSTR = logSTR & Cells(32, "C").Value & " , "

    Open "C:\temp\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ".csv" For Append As #My_filenumber
          Print #My_filenumber, logSTR
    Close #My_filenumber

End Sub
```

But you do know this means you need to add the VBA code to each file you run it on?
You could make it an add-in and access the VBA code "externally" and that way you don't need to copy paste the code to each file.

Comment: This did exactly what I needed it to do! Thank you so much for your help.